In app purchases on Mac(designed for iPad) not working while working on iOS
Following delegate returns proper number of products on iOS but not when run using macOS(designed for iPAD) device in XCODE. I found that similar issue was on mac catalyst and solvable by strong productRequest reference, but here it doesn't work. I use .storekit file for testing that. Any idea?
EDIT: I left .storekit config file testing and stuck it to sandbox testing which works on macOS (designed for iPAD) as expected.
My AppDelegate:
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
        IAPManager.shared.fetchProducts()
        return true
}

my IAPManager:
final class IAPManager: NSObject, SKProductsRequestDelegate,SKPaymentTransactionObserver{
    var productsRequest: SKProductsRequest!

    static let shared = IAPManager()
    
    var products = [SKProduct]()
    
    public func fetchProducts() {
        let request = SKProductsRequest(
            productIdentifiers: Set(Product.allCases.map { $0.rawValue })
        )
        productsRequest = request
        productsRequest.delegate = self
        productsRequest.start()
    }

    func productsRequest(_ request: SKProductsRequest, didReceive response: SKProductsResponse) {
        self.products = response.products
    }

    enum Product:String, CaseIterable{
        case token_10k
        case token_100k
        case token_500k
        
        var count:Int{
            switch self {
            case .token_10k:
                return 10000
            case .token_100k:
                return 100000
            case .token_500k:
                return 500000
            }
        }
    }
}

